# Proper way to sign and install an Office add-in

Tags: visual-studio, ms-office, vsto, clickonce, manifest

I have tried the following on a C#-based Outlook addin called `myaddin` following [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsto/archive/2009/04/29/signing-and-re-signing-manifests-in-clickonce.aspx):

```
mage –update myaddin.manifest –certfile mycert.pfx
mage.exe –update myaddin.vsto –appmanifest myaddin.manifest –certfile mycert.pfx
```

I can install it by manually creating registry keys that specify the path to `myaddin.vsto` with the supplied `|vstolocal` suffix under `Software\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\Addins\myaddin` and it works to install and run `myaddin` that way, however, some customers complain that when they run Outlook it starts the ClickOnce installer for `myaddin.vsto` and gives an error, but this should not happen with `|vstolocal`.

I was able to reproduce this problem by double-clicking `myaddin.vsto`, so I checked the `myaddin.dll.manifest` file and saw that there was a ClickOnce developer certificate referenced there. Could it have been confusing Outlook? I was able to get rid of this ClickOnce developer certificate reference by using a newer .NET 4.5 version of `mage.exe` to update the manifest. Now, if I double-click `myaddin.vsto`, it says that the publisher is not verified and gives me an install button.

Is this the proper way to go about the signing process and the installation process of an Office addin? Why does it complain that the publisher is not valid?

Answer (score 0):

What is the version of VSTO on your development machine ?

Ensure that it is at the least 10.0.50903

Comment: "it starts the ClickOnce installer for myaddin.vsto and gives an error, "       Can you share the details of the error - Screenshot, StackTrace etc